# Oauth 2.0 service provider in WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, oauth-2.0

I need to create a RESTful WCF service and it needs to authenticate callers using OAuth 2.0.
I have been learning OAuth and it's provider implementations for past week and these are the resources I have found that comes close to what I want..

(1)http://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/archive/2008/11/14/oauth-channel-for-wcf-restful-services.aspx
https://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth
(2)http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/523/oauth-dot-net

They are all a bit old(2-3 years) and they are all OAuth 1.0.I want Oauth2.0 because it is simpler.Is there any library out there(in C#) that I can use as a guide for my implementation?

PS: I have found following related posts in StackOverFlow ,but they too are inadequate for my project.
(1)[what is the recommended database structure for OAuth Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4534337/what-is-the-recommended-database-structure-for-oauth-provider/4567086#4567086)
(2)[OAuth Simple Service Provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937777/oauth-simple-service-provider)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DotnetOpenOAuth is a great package that does what you're looking for.  Install the package and look through the samples... http://dotnetopenauth.net/

https://github.com/DotNetOpenAuth/DotNetOpenAuth/blob/master/README.md

Comment: I find the samples to be lacking in regards to WCF.

Comment: This doesn't appear to integrate with WCF at all. @IntStarFoo, can you point out where in the docs for this project they implement OAuth 2.0 support for WCF?